# Tamanho de fonte de texto dentro de um botão

Tags: css, materialize

Como consigo mudar o tamanho da fonte do texto que esta dentro de um botão? Estou usando Materialize.

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn"><i class="material-icons left">featured_play_list</i>Ver Lista de Compras</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn"><i class="material-icons left">update</i>Alterar Produto</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn"><i class="material-icons left">add_circle</i>Cadastrar Produto</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i>Excluir Produto</a>
```

Valeu.

Comment: E o que você sabe de CSS?

Comment: pouco na vdd... hsuahsauhsauhsaushaush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma class em **CSS**.

```
.minhaclass{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Aplica ela depois das classes que já estão sendo chamadas, assim irá sobrepor.

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light grey darken-3 btn minhaclass"><i class="material-icons left">featured_play_list</i>Ver Lista de Compras</a>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, cara...